# maven-license-plugin: Use license for parentPom for all children

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use the maven-license-plugin to get license and header information for a multimodule project.  I want to avoid having multiple copies of the license around and keep the pom files as easy to maintain as possible.  To that end, I've put the plugin information into the parentPom in the  element.  I fully configured the plugin and put the necessary files into the parent project as well.  So, in the parent, I have:

```
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <licenseName>my_license</licenseName>
                        <licenseResolver>${project.baseUri}/src/license</licenseResolver>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>first</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update-file-header</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

I then put a reference to this plugin into one of the children pom files:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The child fails to build though because it tries to find the licenses.properties file along the child's project path, not the parent's.  How do I get the children to look for licenses.properties in the parent project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was to use the classpath  option as described here:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/examples/example-add-license.html

> Using a license resolver from classpath Since version 1.3, it is
>   possible to use a license resolver from classpath (means included into
>   a jar or any dependency of the plugin dependencies).
>
> Just use the classpath:// protocol in the plugin configuration.
>
> Imagine you have a license resolver in an artifact
>   com.my:extraLicenseResolvers:1.0 in package foo.bar
>
> Next example show how to use this license resolver from classpath:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>   <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>   <version>1.6</version>
>   <configuration>
>       <licenseName>my_license</licenseName>
>       <licenseResolver>classpath://foo/bar</licenseResolver>
>   </configuration>
>   <executions>
>       <execution>
>           <goals>
>               <goal>update-file-header</goal>
>           </goals>
>           <phase>process-sources</phase>
>       </execution>
>   </executions>
>   <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.my</groupId>
>           <artifactId>extraLicenseResolvers</artifactId>
>           <version>1.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
> </plugin>
> ```

What wasn't obvious about this is that you really do need to have a separate package with the license files.  There doesn't seem to be a way to keep this information in the parent pom project.

In the end, this solution worked and we were able to have a single location for our license info that all of the children pom files use.

Comment: Yo can also use an external license repository accessible for example via http protocol.